# Add Sum to each row of Listagg in Select

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, listagg

I use the following as part of a larger query which works as intended.

In my case some shipper IDs can have more than one item numbers which would then all be aggregated through the below.

**Example:**
A shipper ID has 3 item numbers.
In this case the below would return 3 items (incl. their details) and 3 gross prices for this shipper ID.

Is there **any way I could sum the gross prices for each shipping ID** ?
Let's say the gross prices in the above example are 10.00, 20.00 and 30.00 then I would like to see a total for this shipper ID of 60.00.
This could be displayed in a separate column if that's easier.

I tried multiple approaches but couldn't get this to work properly.

**My Query:**

```
SELECT
    c.SHIPPER_ID AS Identnummer
    , LISTAGG
    (
        'ITEM NO.: ' || m.ITEM_NUMBER || 
        ' -nl-ARTICLE NAME: ' || a.ARTICLE_NAME || 
        ' -nl-NET PRICE: ' || m.NET_PRICE || 
        ' -nl-TAX: ' || NVL(m.TAX, 0) || 
        ' -nl-GROSS_PRICE: ' || (m.NET_PRICE + m.TAX),
        ' -nl--nl-'
    ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY m.SHIPMENT_ID) AS Article
FROM 
    myTable m
/* ... */
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Am I missing something?  Would you just use `SUM()`:

```
select . . .,
       listagg(. . . ),
       sum(m.NET_PRICE + m.TAX) as total_gross_price
```

Comment: Thanks, Gordon. Maybe I didn't describe it well. Let's say I have 100 shipper IDs. Then some of them have just one item so here the sum for this shipper ID is the same as the gross price for the item. But if a shipper ID has more than one items then I would need to calculate their sum, within the listagg I think. Your approach wouldn't work because there is no gross price outside the listag. Do I see it wrong ?

Comment: @keewee279 . . . You have the component values, so you can put that expression in the `SUM()`.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, I am new to Oracle. So this would work also if there is more than one net price and tax for a shipper ID ?

Comment: @keewee279 . . . Yes.  It is surprising that you understand `listagg()` but not `sum()`.  The latter is much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT c.SHIPPER_ID AS Identnummer
               ,LISTAGG ('ITEM NO.: ' || m.ITEM_NUMBER || ' -nl-ARTICLE NAME: ' || a.ARTICLE_NAME || ' -nl-NET PRICE: ' || m.NET_PRICE ||
                         ' -nl-TAX: ' || NVL (m.TAX, 0) || ' -nl-GROSS_PRICE: ' || (m.NET_PRICE + m.TAX)
                        ,' -nl--nl-')
                WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY m.SHIPMENT_ID)
                    AS Article
               ,c.AMOUNT
           FROM myTable m)
  SELECT Identnummer, Article, SUM (AMOUNT) AS Amount
    FROM CTE
GROUP BY Identnummer, Article
```